# WCF Authentication -- Authenticate user/pass one time, then authenticate some other way afterwards?

Tags: wcf, authentication, https, wshttpbinding, basichttpbinding

Basically, I have the following scenario and information:

- We're using HTTPS.
- We want to authenticate a user by user/pass when they first log in.
- After they are authenticated, I want any future calls to OTHER services (not the login service) to use the username and some sort of session (in case the password changes in the middle of a session).
- I want to make sure my sessions can timeout and control them in a way that if a user tries to call a service and they don't have a session they get an error (cause they haven't logged in). Not sure if there's a WCF built-in way to do sessions this way or if I'll have to do something customized with a database.
- I think we want to use WSHttpBinding (not BasicHttpBinding), 90% sure on this.

I just can't seem to figure out how to do this. Often time's I'll find information on the client code doing `client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username` and `client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password`. But, that just doesn't work because what is my server checking against? I'm trying to grab that info and validate it against a database of user/passes. I'm not looking to use Windows Authentication or that sort (because I don't care who is logged into the computer, just who is logging into the app).

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a Secure Token Service (STS) to authenticate and get a Security Token (maybe SAML) back that identifies the user which can then be passed to your other services and they can just use the identity information to identify and *authorize* because they trust the STS has verified the user's identity up front.

This is a large subject to discuss, so I suggest [searching for WCF STS](http://www.bing.com/search?q=WCF%20STS) and doing some more research, but that's definitely the direction I'd recommend going. If you're going to build your own STS implementation, I also recommend looking into using the [Windows Identity Foundation (WIF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517276.aspx) components to ease your development efforts.

[Here's the download link for WIF v1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=eb9c345f-e830-40b8-a5fe-ae7a864c4d76&displaylang=en) which is the latest version at the time of this answer.

Comment: Is it free? Because when I google WIF it takes me to an MSDN page that says "Download Evaluation" ...

Comment: 100% free. Added v1 download link to answer.